# Connecting MRCP audio with PJSIP

Tags: audio-streaming, pjsip, unimrcp

I am looking for a way to connect the audio stream from an MRCP client/server session to a call answered with PJSIP.  Our server establishes a SIP call with an caller endpoint and then creates a conference with a 2nd (server) endpoint.  This 2nd endpoint is answering the call with PJSIP and also has a UniMRCP client implementation to create an MRCP session with Nuance (on a 3rd server).  I need to be able to connect the audio stream from the MRCP session with the call answered by PJSIP. Can anyone provide any information on how to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Renee